# variable used like a type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

the error is coming in return statement " 'mydata' is a variable but is used like a type "
how to fix the error?

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult NewData()
    {
        List<mydatasample> mydata = new List<mydatasample>(); 
        mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = "test1", publisherName = "yum3", publishYear = 2018 });
        mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = "test1", publisherName = "yum3", publishYear = 2018 });
        mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = "test2", publisherName = "yum3", publishYear = 2018 });
        mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = "test1", publisherName = "yum3", publishYear = 2018 });
        mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = "test1", publisherName = "yum3", publishYear = 2018 });
        mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = "test1", publisherName = "yum3", publishYear = 2018 });
        mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = "test1", publisherName = "yum3", publishYear = 2018 });
        mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = "test1", publisherName = "yum3", publishYear = 2018 });
        mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = "test1", publisherName = "yum3", publishYear = 2018 });
        mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = "test1", publisherName = "yum3", publishYear = 2018 });



        return Json(new mydata { }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Its just `return Json(mydata, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments the error is in the Return

```
   [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult NewData()
    {
        List<mydatasample> mydata = new List<mydatasample>(); 
        mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = "test1", publisherName = "yum3", publishYear = 2018 });
        mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = "test1", publisherName = "yum3", publishYear = 2018 });
        mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = "test2", publisherName = "yum3", publishYear = 2018 });
        mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = "test1", publisherName = "yum3", publishYear = 2018 });
        mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = "test1", publisherName = "yum3", publishYear = 2018 });
        mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = "test1", publisherName = "yum3", publishYear = 2018 });
        mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = "test1", publisherName = "yum3", publishYear = 2018 });
        mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = "test1", publisherName = "yum3", publishYear = 2018 });
        mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = "test1", publisherName = "yum3", publishYear = 2018 });
        mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = "test1", publisherName = "yum3", publishYear = 2018 });



        return Json(mydata, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are creating another object on return statement. Please remove the new keyword and {} from the return line.

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult NewData()
{
    List<mydatasample> mydata = new List<mydatasample>(); 
    mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = "test1", publisherName = "yum3", publishYear = 2018 });
    mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = "test1", publisherName = "yum3", publishYear = 2018 });
    mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = "test2", publisherName = "yum3", publishYear = 2018 });
    mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = "test1", publisherName = "yum3", publishYear = 2018 });
    mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = "test1", publisherName = "yum3", publishYear = 2018 });
    mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = "test1", publisherName = "yum3", publishYear = 2018 });
    mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = "test1", publisherName = "yum3", publishYear = 2018 });
    mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = "test1", publisherName = "yum3", publishYear = 2018 });
    mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = "test1", publisherName = "yum3", publishYear = 2018 });
    mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = "test1", publisherName = "yum3", publishYear = 2018 });



    return Json(mydata, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```